# Добавление символа в конец строки

Tags: php, html, javascript

Подскажите, каким образом реализовать такое:

Есть форма, которая отправляет данные в БД.
Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы при записи строки в БД в конец строки добавлялся символ или цифра?

Вот код запроса.

```
if (!empty($_POST))
{
    $result = mysql_query ("SELECT url FROM woo_pages WHERE url ='$url'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
        {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO woo_pages (url,name) VALUES ('$url','$name')");  
            echo "Запрос отправлен";
        }
            else
                {
                    echo "Данная запись существует";
                }

}
```

Смысл в том, чтобы если запись повторяется, то в таком случае в конец записи добавлялась цифра или символ.

Comment: Мне одному кажется странным, что человек дошел до работы с БД пропустив работу со строками?

`$str .= '!';`

Comment: @Dem, если посмотреть вопросы г-на @kostya, то появялется мысль, что до работы с БД дошёл ХэшКод

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert into `table` ( `string` ) values ( concat( "lalala", "!" ) )
```

За упрощение прошу ногами не пинать :)

Answer (score 5):

Хм..

```
$variable  = 'Я строка и без разницы как я сюда попала';
$something = 'Символ или Цифра';
$variable .= $something; // Ура, я сделал это!
save_to_db($variable);   // Записал Это в БД
```

Какая-то [ссылка](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2172211/)..

Answer (score -1):

Еще вариант:

```
$variable  = 'Я строка и без разницы как я сюда попала'; 
$something = '!!!!!!!';        //Символ или Цифра

$string = substr_replace($variable, $something, strlen($variable), 0); 
print_r($string);
```

Получим:

```
Я строка и без разницы как я сюда попала!!!!!!!
```

Comment: Приколько.​​​​​